# modify a method from an extended class

Tags: java, class, methods, import

So i have a class file that extends `java.lang.object` called powerfulS
And i use this class file in my `Testers.java` as such

```
import java.lang.object;

public class Testers
{

 public static powerfulS=new powerfuls(..); 

 [..]

}
```

now i have a dilemma in which my class powerfulS has a method which needs to be modified. And the method in this class uses other methods within that class
    e.g

```
public double method1()
{

 return getPowerLvl()*getSystemCrasher();

}
```

i want to change it so that it uses another method in that class as such

e.g

```
public double method1()
{

 return getPowerLvl()*getSystemReviver();

}
```

When i attempted to do this

```
public class Testers
{

 public double method1()
{

 return super.getPowerLvl()*super.getSystemCrasher();

} 

 public static powerfulS=new powerfuls(..); 

 [..]

}
```

I get a 'cannot find symbol error'.... How do I modify the method in the imported class? Do I use `@Override` ?

Comment: Why would one import Object????

Comment: Your Testers classe extend Object class and Object class doesn't define any method called "method1". Hence the exception

Comment: Im currently learning on how to use classes if it were extended to the java.lang.object cause the class extends there. So in order to use the class i need to import java.lang.object

Comment: @sol4me the strucuture is as such
powerfulS extends java.lang.object
testers imports java.lang.object to access powerfulS
And i need to modify a method within powerfulS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The keyword super applies to Parent class, so in your case you are trying to call the method of Object class which doesn't exist.

```
public class Testers
{

 public double method1()
{

 //You are calling super.getPowerLv1() * super.getSystemCrasher()
 //return super.getPowerLvl()*super.getSystemCrasher();
 // remove the super keyword like and call method from powerfuls getPowerLv1() and getSystemCrasher
 return powerfulS.getPowerLvl()* powerfulS.getSystemCrasher();

} 

 public static powerfulS=new powerfuls({
    public double method1()
      {
           //here you can ovverride this method how you will like
        return super.getPowerLvl()*super.getSystemCrasher() + 1 + 1;

      }
 }); 

 [..]

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. Its helpful for me to further understand java.. This place is quite harsh to newbies huh....

Comment: If you find it useful and it answer your question then you can accept it as the answer.

Comment: But it doesn't really answer my question cause i need to modify a method that exist within another class . That class extends to java.lang.object so i need to access that class method and override it with my own definition of that method...

Comment: In your Testers class you will like to call the method getPowerLvl() which is defined in powerfulS ? right?

Comment: Yes and no. I want to call it which im able but I need to modify that method to do what i need